# Inno Setup - Checking existence of file in {pf}

Tags: inno-setup

I want to add a prerequisite check to the Inno Setup recipe to check that a file exists under `C:\Program Files (x86)\XYZ` folder.

Apparently the constants such as `{pf}` are not set when `InitializeSetup` gets called.

What is the proper way to do such validations?

```pascal
[Code]

function HasRequirements(): boolean;
begin
  result := FileExists('{pf}\XYZ\file.exe')
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    MsgBox('{pf}', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if not HasRequirements() then begin
        MsgBox('Please install XYZ first.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        result := false;
    end else
        result := true;
end;
```

Comment: You can call system default [Windows Environment Variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) `ExpandConstant{%ProgramFiles}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually expand the constants in your strings using the `ExpandConstant` function:

```
function HasRequirements(): boolean;
begin
  result := FileExists(ExpandConstant('{pf}\XYZ\file.exe'))
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{pf}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if not HasRequirements() then begin
        MsgBox('Please install XYZ first.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        result := false;
    end else
        result := true;
end;
```